# Object declared without initializer is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, http, submit

When I define an object within the subscribe method, this object appears to be undefined when I try to assign a value to it.
Both “_file” and “this.fileObjects” appear to be undefined.
Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataTransferService} from '../data-transfer.service';
import {DataModelService} from '../data-model.service';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-open-selector',
  templateUrl: './open-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./open-selector.component.css']
})
export class OpenSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  fileObjects:File[];
  constructor(private fData:DataTransferService, public location:Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFileList();
  }

   private getFileList() {
     this.fileObjects = [];
      this.fData.getFileList().subscribe((files) => {
        let _file:File;
        for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
          let tmpArray:string[];
          tmpArray = files[i].split('|');
          _file.fileName = files[i];
          _file.owner = tmpArray[0];
          _file.brand = tmpArray[1];
          _file.serial = tmpArray[2];
          _file.flags = tmpArray[3];
          this.fileObjects.push(_file);
        }  
      });
    }

}

interface File {
    fileName:string,
    owner:string,
    brand:string,
    serial:string,
    flags:string
}
```

Displays the following error message in the console:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_file.fileName = files[i]')

Comment: Can you try `let _file:File = {};`?

Comment: *When I define an object". You're **declaring a variable**, not "defining an object". *try to assign a value to it* No, you're trying to assign a value to a property of it.

Comment: Problem solved: 

let _file:File={"fileName":"", "owner":"","brand":"","serial":"","flags":""}; did the trick.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Since _file is undefined `let _file:File;` here. When you make an assignment like `_file.fileName = files[i];` it will throw an

> "Can't find fileName of undefined"

error.

So initialize your variable `let _file:File = {};`

Comment: Gives type '{}' is nog assignable to type 'File'

Comment: @Mark you can change it to `let _file:any = {};` or maybe `let _file:File = {} as any;`

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you have to declare and then define the variable.

`let _file;` // this declared the variable. But the default value is `undefined`

Also, in the `this` object which is part of the js function, there is no value named `fileObjects`. Therefor, it's undefined as well.

The solution would be to define the values before trying to use them.

```
private getFileList() {

    this.fileObjects = []; // fileObjects defined as array

    this.fData.getFileList().subscribe((files) => {

    let _file:File = {}; // assign empty value to _file

         for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
              let tmpArray:string[];
              tmpArray = files[i].split('|');
              _file.fileName = files[i];
              _file.owner = tmpArray[0];
              _file.brand = tmpArray[1];
              _file.serial = tmpArray[2];
              _file.flags = tmpArray[3];
              this.fileObjects.push(_file);
         }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Best practice would be to use `const` instead of `let`.

Comment: "let _file:File = {};" gives type '{}' is nog assignable to type 'File'

Comment: let _file:File={"fileName":"", "owner":"","brand":"","serial":"","flags":""}; did the trick.

Comment: @Mark TS must be checking for the correct typings. You should be able to do `File = new File()` as well.